# if an input radio is checked change the parent's color: can't make it work with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, label

When I click an `input` radio, `<label>`'s text should change it's text color.

However it doesn't do the trick with my jQuery code:

```
$("#radios").find("input").change(function(){
if ($(this).checked)
    $(this).parent().addClass('libelulas');
else
    $(this).parent().removeClass('libelulas');
});
```

I've been checking with the inspector in chrome and seems like it doesn't even create the class wherever is the parent (label) or the input.

Here's my jsfiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/Arkl1te/2MnEU/4/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to wrap it in `$(document).ready` and use a correct selector on the `change()` event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".radios input[type=radio]").change(function(){
      $(this).parent().addClass('libelulas');
  });
});
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2MnEU/6/)

---

### Update:

Forgot to give example in relation to your code in the question and not just the jsFiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".radios input[type=radio]").change(function(){
      $(this).parent().addClass('libelulas');
      $("input[type=radio]:not(:checked)").parent().removeClass('libelulas');
  }); 
});
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2MnEU/10/)

Comment: @Fabián Oops sorry, I only included your jsFiddle code in my answer instead of the code in your question

Comment: It's ok man, that code gave me the idea to figure how to do it properly. Now it works and that's what matters :)